# singleTask mode & task back stack

Tags: android, back-stack, launchmode

Could please someone give me an example of how we can create a task back stack with having an Activity, which has launchMode=singleTask, at top of the stack and it's not the only activity in the back stack.

For example, we have one such task in the below diagram (the one including Activity X & Y);

[image]

As far as I know, singleTask activity is supposed to be the root one and task elements can never be rearranged.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an app `Application1` with four Activities:

   - `Activity1`

     - Make sure that it **is not** `exported="false"` (that is, it's `true` either explicitly or implicitly)
     - Make it the launcher
   - `Activity2`
   - `ActivityX`
   - `ActivityY`

     - It's the one: `launchMode="singleTask"`
2. In `Activity1` implement two actions, e.g. two distinct buttons each doing the following:

   - Start `Activity2` and finish itself
   - Start `Activity2` and **do not** finish itself
3. In `Activity2` implement two actions:

   - Start `ActivityX` and finish itself
   - Start `ActivityY` and **do not** finish itself
4. In `ActivityX` implement one action:

   - Start `ActivityY` and **do not** finish itself
5. `ActivityY` do nothing :)
6. Create another app `Application2` with an Activity:

   - `AnotherActivity`

     - Make it the launcher
7. In `AnotherActivity` implement one action:

   - Start `Activity1`. You can do it like this:

```java
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        // package, fully qualified class name
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
            "com.stackoverflow", "com.stackoverflow.Activity1");
        startActivity(intent);
```

8. Launch `Application1`, which will start `Activity1`
9. In `Activity1`, start `Activity2` finishing itself
10. In `Activity2`, start `ActivityX` finishing itself
11. In `ActivityX`, start `ActivityY`
12. Press home
13. Launch `Application2`, which will start `AnotherActivity`
14. In `AnotherActivity`, start `Activity1`
15. In `Activity1`, start `Activity2` **without** finishing itself
16. In `Activity2`, start `ActivityY` **without** finishing itself

There you go. Pop the stack with the back button now.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is pretty easy to do.

To generate a task that contains `X` at the root and `Y` on top, even though `Y` is declared with `launchMode="singleTask"`:

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <activity android:name=".X">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Y" android:launchMode="singleTask"/>
</application>
```

In activity `X` just launch activity `Y` like this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, SingleTaskActivity.class));
```

You will now have a task with activity `X` at the root and activity `Y` on top of that.

This happens even if you explicitly say that you want `Y` launched in a new task, like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SingleTaskActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

This seems counter-intuitive, but the reason is because both `X` and `Y` have the same `taskAffinity`. And `taskAffinity` trumps `launchMode` when Android needs to decide how to launch an `Activity`.

`taskAffinity`, if not specifically set, defaults to the package name of the application. All activities with the same `taskAffinity` will be launched into the same task.

This confuses most developers, because the documentation doesn't mention `taskAffinity` very often.

If you really want to be sure that an `Activity` will always be the root of its task, no matter how it is launched, you need to use either `launchMode="singleTask"` or `launchMode="singleInstance"` **and** specify `taskAffinity=""` to indicate that the `Activity` has no task affinity (ie: it doesn't belong with any other activities).